# Parse.com - Strange includeKey issue

Tags: key, parse-platform

I have a compound query as shown below.

```
 - (PFQuery *)queryForPhotos {

        if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAPPhotoClassKey];
            [query setLimit:0];
            return query;
        }

        // Query for users with the same language level
        PFQuery *sameLevelUsersQuery = [PFUser query];
        [sameLevelUsersQuery whereKey:kWSUserLanguageLevelKey equalTo:[[PAPCache sharedCache] languageLevelForUser:[PFUser currentUser]]];
        sameLevelUsersQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
        sameLevelUsersQuery.limit = 1000;

        PFQuery *photosFromSameLevelUsersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAPPhotoClassKey];
        [photosFromSameLevelUsersQuery whereKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey matchesQuery:sameLevelUsersQuery];
        [photosFromSameLevelUsersQuery whereKeyExists:kPAPPhotoPictureKey];


        [photosFromSameLevelUsersQuery whereKey:kWSUniversalIsDeletedKey notEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        [photosFromSameLevelUsersQuery includeKey:kWSPhotoCommentObjectForTitleKey]; // THE INCLUDED KEY IN QUESTION
        [photosFromSameLevelUsersQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

        // A pull-to-refresh should always trigger a network request.
        [photosFromSameLevelUsersQuery setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];

        return photosFromSameLevelUsersQuery;

    }
```

If I leave this line in:

```
        [photosFromSameLevelUsersQuery includeKey:kWSPhotoCommentObjectForTitleKey]; // THE INCLUDED KEY IN QUESTION
```

Then I get only 1 photoObject that contains a commentObject in that field. However, 3 of the (currently) 26 photos in the DB have commentObjects in that field, therefore I should get 3 photos with something in that field. The one commentObject DOES load with all of it's fields.

HOWEVER, if I leave out that `includeKey` line, then all 3 of the photoObjects with something in that field DO return a commentObject in that field. HOWEVER, in this case the objects are empty and I have to call `fetchIfNeeded` to retrieve their data.

I'd rather not do this and have to reload the tableView on callback if I can get the data loaded the first time the correct way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What is `photosQuery`?

Should that be:

```
[photosFromSameLevelUsersQuery includeKey:kWSPhotoCommentObjectForTitleKey];
```

Comment: Shoot. I somehow got a couple methods mixed up when copying/pasting/cleaning up code. The method as I ran it is now shown, and it was `photosFromSameLevelUsersQuery` when ran, so that wasn't the issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Oh man. So it was an ACL issue. For others coming to this question that are newish to Parse and to data storage in general, I'm finding that a lot of strange issues come back to ACL issues.

Otherwise the issue was very specific:

- I noticed that my ACL's on the newer comments I stored where set to:

  {"*":{"write":true}}

Which was exactly the problem. There wasn't a read ACL set at all, so the Comment Objects couldn't be read by anyone.

Why did this happen?

- I had setup this cloud code previously because I wanted to alter a Comment Object by someone other than the object creator:

  ```
    Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Comments", function(request, response) {

          Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

          // Check if the isTitle field is being modified
          var dirty = request.object.dirty("isTitle");

          if (dirty == true) {
                console.log("dirty == true");

                var publicWriteACL = new Parse.ACL();
                publicWriteACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);

                request.object.setACL(publicWriteACL);
          }

          response.success();
      });
  ```

Previously there was only one instance where I was setting the `isTitle` field, and in that case I wanted others to have write access.

HOWEVER, I was having problems with this, so I started setting the `isTitle` field when a Comment Object was created, and thus the conditional in the cloudCode beforeSave method was being called, changing the ACL's.

---

One thing to note about Parse.com is that when using `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` in beforeSave the ACL changes are supposed to be scoped only to that function. I believe that's the case - if someone has more correct info on this please correct me. HOWEVER, it seems that in this case the ACL changes became permanent.

This might have been because it was during the creation of the object VS a subsequent save.